# Laravel installation issues

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

After using this:

```
laravel new website
```

I'm getting this error. Does anyone knows what i did wrong? I'm using  512 MB / 20 GB Disk / Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64 on digitalocean.

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.28)
- Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.28)
Downloading: 100%         

Created project in website
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- symfony/thanks v1.0.1 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/thanks v1.0.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
- Installation request for symfony/thanks ^1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/thanks[v1.0.0, v1.0.1].

Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your    minimum-stability setting
 see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with composer.
Try updating composer with `sudo composer self-update` and try again.

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException]             
  Command "self-update" is not defined.

Comment: And when i try for example sudo composer update. I will get the same error as above.

Comment: What is the current composer version ? `composer --version`

Comment: Composer version @package_branch_alias_version@ (1.0.0-beta2) 2016-03-27 16:00:34

Comment: Ok, you may try updating composer with `composer global update composer/composer`

Comment: Changed current directory to /home/jan/.composer
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /home/jan/.composer
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section. Just do that? Why isn't it already installing lastest version i don't get it.

Comment: Seems your composer is not globally installed. You can install composer with your package manager for the latest version. Ex: In ubuntu : `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install composer`